# How can I create the right menu link with Typo3 DataProcessor to translated pages?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a problem with the DataProcessor / MenuProcessor in Typo3 8.7.
My site have two languages German (L=0) and English (L=2). In German all navigation links are OK, but when I switch to English, the main navigation translate all menu items to English, but the links shows to the german pages, not to the english ones.

The links should look like this:

German = /ueber-uns/

English = /en/about-us/

Links are working, realUrl do the Job. In my LanguageMenu the link translation works. But in my main navigation not.

My MainNavigationProcessor is:

```
dataProcessing {
  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
  10 {
    levels = 2
    includeSpacer = 1
    as = mainnavigation
  }
}
```

My LanguageMenu is:

```
dataProcessing {
  40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
  40 {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,2 
    as = languagenavigation
    if.isTrue = 0,2
  }
}
```

A dump show this:

[image]

What do I wrong?

Comment: Ohh No, I forgot to set config.linkVars = L. Now all works like a charme

Comment: Could you throw this in an answer of yourself with a code sample that works now and accept this? Would be helpful for others facing the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is solved. In Typo3 Setup this line helps:

```
config.linkVars = L
```

Better:

```
config.linkVars = L(0-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define special type value like `special.value` not only `value` because of here you have use special menu for language.

Try this typoscript.

```
dataProcessing {
  40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
  40 {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,2 
    as = languagenavigation
    if.isTrue = 0,2
  }
}
```

Comment: Your right. That was my mistake here on Stackoverflow. I have special.value. The LanguageMenu works, I have the problem with the mainnavigation.